# What is the best way to implement a link yii2 -> React js?

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, yii2

What is the best way to implement a link yii2 -> React js?

In general, can this be done or do you need another tool?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try [this widget](https://github.com/bTokman/yii2-react).It's can be helpful if you interesting in server-side rendering

Answer (score 2):

In general you can use React in any of server frameworks if you are using it for frontend. that has nothing to do with what technology you use on server.

short answer: it's almost same as including a jquery library

look at this example: http://jsbin.com/cuneha/1/edit?html,js,output

```
<script src="react-0.13.1.js"></script>
```

That's react library

Long answer: you might need react, react-dom and other libraries. React is usually written in jsx. before you send to browser you might want to compile back into plain js. babel, webpack/browserify is general tool used to bundle and convert this stuff.

React architecture works best with single page framework.